# Find the conditional distribution to calculate a probability

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional

I have a question that has been posed to me with 4 multiple choice answers. I cannot see how any of these answers are correct. Can somebody please let me know how to solve this? I'm getting $e^{-1}$ as my result and would like to see if this could be checked.

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the following joint probability density function:

$$
f_{XY}(x,y) = \begin{cases}
      2e^{-x-y} & 0<x<y<\infty\\
      0 & \text{elsewhere.}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Find the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ and use it to calculate $\mathbb{P}(Y>2|X=1).$

Possible answers:
a) 1/3 ,
b) 0 ,
c) 1/2 ,
d) $e^{-2}$

I have been asked to show my working so here goes:
$$
f_{Y|X}(y|x)=f_{XY}(x,y)/f_{X}(x) \\
f_{X}(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}f(x,y) dy = 2e^{-x}\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-y}dy = 2e^{-2x}\\
$$

Therefore $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = 2e^{-x-y}/2e^{-2x} = e^{x-y}$

This leads me to
$$
\mathbb{P}(Y>2|X=1) = \int_{2}^{\infty}e^{1-y}dy =-e^{1-y}\Big|_{2}^{\infty} = e^{-1}
$$

Any help to see where I have gone wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you showed your work we might be able to point out where you went awry

Comment: On a basic skimming through your answer, I think your calculations are correct.